# How to find a program that will add the sums of numbers that are divisible by only certain numbers

Tags: python

Sorry, I am new to Python. I want to find a Python program that will find the sum of integers 1 to n that are divisible by a and b but not by c.

For example, if

```
n = 20, a = 3, b = 4 and c = 5
```

we would have:

```
3 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 9 + 12 + 16
```

The code I have right now is something like:

```
   def summing(n):
        x = sum(k for k in xrange(n) if (k%3==0) or (k%4==0))
        return x - sum(k for k in xrange(n) if (k%5==0))
```

But, I know this isn't right because it subtracts multiples of 5 even if they aren't divisible by 3 or 4.

Comment: `sum(k for k in xrange(1, n) if k % a == 0 and k % b == 0 and k % c != 0)`

Comment: Do you mean ".. that are divisible by a or divisible by b, but not divisible by c"?

Comment: If you really want integers from 1 to `n` inclusive, you probably want to make your `xrange` call `xrange(1, n+1)`. Python's ranges start ant zero and are exclusive of the upper bound, so `n` won't be included otherwise (and zero will, but that's fairly harmless).

Answer (score 2):

```
def sumNumInRange(n):
    return sum(k for k in xrange(n) if k % 5 != 0 and (k % 3 == 0 or k % 4 == 0))
```

Also consider not to hardcode values like `3`, `4` and `5`. It might be better to pass those as arguments to function.

Comment: probably a good idea to change the function name since sum is already a function in python

Comment: I didn't downvote but it was probably because you hardcoded the 3, 4, and 5.  You should make the function accept arguments `a`, `b`, and `c`.  Still seems a little silly to downvote for that though...